# Automatic JSONModel instantiation

Tags: sapui5

I have a application with the following structure:

```
`| index.html
| |
+---webapp
| |Component.js
| |manifest.json
| |
| +---controller
| |Detail.controller.js
| |Master.controller.js
| |
| +---service
| | data.json
| |
| \---view
| App.view.xml
| Detail.view.xml
| Master.view.xml`
```

My manifest file defines a data source as follows:

Under sap.app:

```
"dataSources": {
"mainService": {
"uri": "/service/data.json",
"type": "JSON"
}
}
```

I have also tried the uri parameter with the path "service/data.json" but didn't work either.

Under sap.ui5:

```
"models": {
"": {
"dataSource": "mainService",
"type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel"
},
"i18n": {
"type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
"settings": {
"bundleName": "sapui5.demo.mvcapp.i18n.i18n"
}
}
}
```

My Component.js has the following code:

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/core/UIComponent", "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"], function( UIComponent, JSONModel)
{
    "use strict";
    return UIComponent.extend("sapui5.demo.mvcapp.Component",
    {

        metadata :
        {
            manifest : "json"
        },

        init : function()
        {
            // callthebasecomponent's initfunction
            UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

            // createtheviewsbasedontheurl/hash
            this.getRouter().initialize();

        },

        createContent : function()
        {
            var oRootView = UIComponent.prototype.createContent.apply(this,
                    arguments);

            return oRootView;
        }
    });
});
```

My index.html has the following script code:

```
    sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
    sap.ui.require([
    "sap/m/Shell",
    "sap/ui/core/ComponentContainer",
    "sapui5/demo/mvcapp/Component"],
    function(Shell, ComponentContainer, Component) 
    {
        new Shell({
        app: new ComponentContainer({
             height: "100%",
             component: new Component({
             id: "mvcAppComponent"
             })
        })
      }).placeAt("content");
    });
        });
```

I am not able to get my data to be displayed from the local json file on the table. There are no errors on the console and the table in the master view is empty "No Data".

It looks like the manifest file has no effect at all as my routing is also not working and I am not sure how my Master view is displayed because even when I mess up the name of my master view it is still displayed which shows that the manifest file is not taken into effect.

Can you please show me where I have gone wrong?

Regards, Salah.

Comment: The above chunck is under "sap.app". Also under "sap.ui5": I have this code:"models": {
"": {
"dataSource": "mainService",
"type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel"
},

Comment: If the data is loaded correctly it would be useful to the table definition and the structure of your data.

Answer (score 0):

## It's a relative path to Component.js

*(Given that the problem is with data loading, and not data binding, the following applies. For data binding issues, please post the code snippet of the binding of your controls)*

The `manifest.json` file is already inside `webapp` folder structure. Since the `URI` address is a relative path according to the Component.js ([see here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da.html)), you need to specify the model as the following, for your specific case:

```
"dataSources": {
    "mainService": {
        "uri": "/service/data.json",
        "type": "JSON"
    } }
```